# LIKE '%viagra%'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I use Wordpress and I have just been hacked. I try to clean up a maximum. While searching for "Viagra" in my database, I saw this:

```
SELECT *  FROM `NameBDD`.`wp_options` WHERE (CONVERT(`option_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%viagra%' OR CONVERT(`option_name` USING utf8) LIKE '%viagra%' OR CONVERT(`option_value` USING utf8) LIKE '%viagra%' OR CONVERT(`autoload` USING utf8) LIKE '%viagra%')
```

Knowing nothing, can you tell me if this code is bad, what do he want to say?

Thx !

Cordially.

Comment: I suspect the conversion to utf8 is unnecessary.

Comment: This code by itself is not bad since there is no context for the code. But it might be bad when put into the right context, i.e. if there are entries in the database which match the where clause and if the result of the select is used then for something malicious.